# How can i call a function written in reactjs through an external javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

lets say i have a testfunction written in reactjs just before the rendering, in the index.js file

```
function testfunction(){
console.log("this is test function written in reactjs")
}
```

and i want to call the above reactjs function in html script.

```
<html>
<body>

//including reactjs minified js in the index.html
<script src="reactjs.min.js"></script>

<script>
//here i want to call function written in reactjs file
testfunction();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: only way to make it global or use IIFE

Answer (score 2):

It's ugly and bad practice, but you can set a function to global (window) context so that other scripts can call it:

```
window.testfunction = () => console.log("this is test function written in reactjs");
```

Then, other scripts on the page, having access to `window`, will be able to call it.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. if i use this in production, what would be the side effects of using this as global function?

Comment: It pollutes the global namespace and will make larger applications more difficult to refactor and debug later. It would be better to integrate your page script with your react script, that way they have access to the same scope.